# Safest way to duplicate failing sd card

Tags: backup, data-recovery, sd-card, dd, data-loss

I have a 64 gb SD card that is starting to have problems. I want to duplicate as much of it as I can. Is DD the safest/best option to deal with failing sd cards?

Comment: `ddrescue`  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)

Comment: @guiverc That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ddrescue` myself.

I'd suggest looking up https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery for more information, and especially note the caution:

> You should NOT write to the failed device, as it can worsen a hardware
>   failure, and overwrite existant data in case of lost files .

(it's covered in the *Imaging a damaged device, filesystem or drive* section)